# String index out of range error while trying to make a loop

Tags: java

I am making a program to read a SIN but when I run it, it shows

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at C7Q4.input(C7Q4.java:51)
        at C7Q4.main(C7Q4.java:20)
```

I've tried to switch the "count" char value to an int but got the same error.

```
c.println ("Enter a Social Insurance Number");

numbers = c.readLine ();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length () ; i++)
    {
        if (Character.isDigit (numbers.charAt (i)))
        {

            count++;

            digitone = numbers.charAt (count); 
            digittwo = numbers.charAt (count);
            digitthree = numbers.charAt (count);
            digitfourth = numbers.charAt (count);
            digitfifth = numbers.charAt (count);
            digitsixth = numbers.charAt (count);
            digitseventh = numbers.charAt (count);
            digiteighth = numbers.charAt (count);
            digitninth = numbers.charAt (count);
            firstdigit = Character.getNumericValue (digitone); 
            seconddigit = Character.getNumericValue (digittwo);
            thirddigit = Character.getNumericValue (digitthree);
            fourthdigit = Character.getNumericValue (digitfourth);
            fifthdigit = Character.getNumericValue (digitfifth);
            sixthdigit = Character.getNumericValue (digitsixth);
            seventhdigit = Character.getNumericValue (digitseventh);
            eighthdigit = Character.getNumericValue (digiteighth);
            ninthdigit = Character.getNumericValue (digitninth);
        }
        else
        {
            error = "yes";
            c.println ("Error: You must've put a character that wasn't a number"); 
            c.println ("Do you want to start over");
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping for it to loop 9 times to convert all the numbers in the string in separate chars but it crashes.

Comment: I don't think you understand how loops work. `digitOne through digitNine` will all be the same digit because it's all in the same loop

Comment: every loop iteration is going to set every digit to the current char, also, what was your input string? I'm glad you included the error, but we need to know the input so that the error will actually mean something in this case

Comment: Any 9 digit string causes an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// The "MepzzGay" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class C7Q4
{
    static Console c;           // The output console
    static char num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9;
    static int dig1, dig2, dig3, dig4, dig5, dig6, dig7, dig8, dig9, sum1, sum2;
    static int sumOfS1 = 0, combinedSum, finalDigit;
    static String sinNum;
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();
        input ();
        processing ();
        c.println ("");
        c.println ("");
        stepOne ();
        stepTwo ();
        c.println ("");
        c.println ("");
        stepThree ();
        c.println ("");
        c.println ("");
        stepFour ();
        c.println ("");
        c.println ("");
        stepFive ();
        // Place your program here.  'c' is the output console
    } // main method


    public static void input ()
    {
        c.println ("Hello!");
        c.println ("please enter your SIN number with no spaces");
        sinNum = c.readLine ();

    }


    public static void processing ()
    {
        String str = (sinNum);
        num1 = str.charAt (0);
        num2 = str.charAt (1);
        num3 = str.charAt (2);
        num4 = str.charAt (3);
        num5 = str.charAt (4);
        num6 = str.charAt (5);
        num7 = str.charAt (6);
        num8 = str.charAt (7);
        num9 = str.charAt (8);
        dig1 = Character.getNumericValue (num1);
        dig2 = Character.getNumericValue (num2);
        dig3 = Character.getNumericValue (num3);
        dig4 = Character.getNumericValue (num4);
        dig5 = Character.getNumericValue (num5);
        dig6 = Character.getNumericValue (num6);
        dig7 = Character.getNumericValue (num7);
        dig8 = Character.getNumericValue (num8);
        dig9 = Character.getNumericValue (num9);
    }


    public static void stepOne ()
    {
        dig2 = dig2 * 2;
        dig4 = dig4 * 2;
        dig6 = dig6 * 2;
        dig8 = dig8 * 2;
    }


    public static void stepTwo ()
    {
        String str = "" + dig2 + dig4 + dig6 + dig8;
        String numberOnly = str.replaceAll ("[^0-9]", "");

        try
        {
            sum1 = Integer.parseInt (numberOnly);
        }


        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            sum1 = 0;
        }

        int numbers = sum1;
        while (numbers > 0)
        {
            sumOfS1 = sumOfS1 + numbers % 10;
            numbers = numbers / 10;
        }
        c.println ("Digits #2,4,6,8 multiplied by 2 then, all digits added together");
        c.println (sumOfS1);

    }


    public static void stepThree ()
    {
        sum2 = dig1 + dig3 + dig5 + dig7;
        c.println ("Digits #1,3,5,7");
        c.println (sum2);
    }


    public static void stepFour ()
    {
        combinedSum = sumOfS1 + sum2;
        c.println ("Sum of the two sums combined");
        c.println (combinedSum);
    }


    public static void stepFive ()
    {
        int roundUp = (int) (Math.ceil (combinedSum / 10) * 10);
        c.println ("("+combinedSum+"-"+roundUp+")*-1");

        finalDigit = combinedSum + roundUp * (-1);
        c.println (finalDigit);
        if (finalDigit == dig9)

            {
                c.println ("This is correct");
            }
        else if (finalDigit != dig9)
        {
            c.println ("This is incorrect");
        }
    }
} // MepzzGay class
```

Comment: I guess you guys are in the same class... Does it make sense to give others the code without explanations, instead of letting them do their homework themselves?